# Adhoc App Fails to install on the device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ad-hoc-distribution

I have iPad which is on iOS 5.

Today I have started getting error message saying :"iTunes Sync: <<AppName>> failed to install"

Because of this I am unable to install an adhoc app.

Please help.

Comment: Please explain what you've done so far, so we can help spot what's wrong.

Comment: I am creating the adhoc the way I always do. I am not new to creating adhoc. Till yesterday, I was able to install adhco fine. Its today that I have started getting this error for multiple adhocs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340185/failed-to-install-iphone-application-for-ad-hoc/14266340#14266340

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340185/failed-to-install-iphone-application-for-ad-hoc/14266340#14266340

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340185/failed-to-install-iphone-application-for-ad-hoc/14266340#14266340

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340185/failed-to-install-iphone-application-for-ad-hoc/14266340#14266340

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

It turns out that we were using the wrong Entitlement.plist. Ideally this file should have 3 rows, whereas the one which we were using just had one row.

Comment: The Entitlement.plist was the origin of my problems with Ad Hoc... Check https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3821500?start=0&tstart=0 And http://oleb.net/blog/2011/06/code-signing-changes-in-xcode-4/ has more usefull info: "If you have previously created an Entitlements.plist file for Ad Hoc distribution, you can delete it. Also remove the filename from your build settings if you have listed it under “Code Signing Entitlements”. Skip this step if you require an entitlements file for other purposes than code signing. In this case, just remove the get-task-allow option from the property list."

Answer (score 5):

Please refer to:

[Why does an ad hoc ipa fail to install on one device, yet succeed on another with the same iOS version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931387/why-does-an-ad-hoc-ipa-fail-to-install-on-one-device-yet-succeed-on-another-wit)

It has a comment by the questioner(Alyoshak) says:

> Problem solved. Device id was missing from provisioning profile. I'm
>   leaving the issue here rather than simply deleting it bc it might help
>   others. Must add that iTunes used to give a more specific message when
>   this occurred, and since I had not removed the device id from the list
>   in the iPhone Dev Center (have no idea how it vanished) I didn't
>   consider that this cd actually be the cause. Hope this helps someone
>   misled by the vagueness of the error msg.

This might be the reason where in you might have deselected device Id from the profile.