# Failed to install iphone application for ad hoc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, app-store, distribution

I followed the stepped to create a ad hoc carefully:

1. Added the testers team devices to the devices list in iOs Provisioning profile page
2. Created a new distribution profile for ad-hoc
3. In xcode I chose the project and clicked on product->archive.
4. I sent both the archive (ipa file) and mobile provision to the testers team.

The application failed to install.

I saw an answer of a developer to set in build settings the provisioning file to Code Signing Identities to the distribution profile [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552202/ad-hoc-distribution-app-failed-to-install)

In the list I can see only iOS Team Provisioning Profile that was created by xcode.

This is probably not the distribution profile.

What is missing? How can I set the build settings to the distribution ones?

Comment: The thing I see missing in your steps is importing the profile to Xcode. Did you do that? if not, it would explain not seeing it in the code sign choices.

Comment: Have you created your provisioning profile after adding the device to ur developer account or before.. if before then try recreation provisioning after you add the device..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the IOS Provisioning Portal, in the Provisioning page, click the 'Download' button by your new distribution profile and it should get added to XCode.

To check you have it, go to XCode Organizer, Devices, then Library / Provisioning Profiles on the left.

Comment: I also had to press refresh in the provisioning profile to show it up

Answer (score 1):

You may also use https://testflightapp.com.

This is a free service and works very reliably - you can manage your testers and test ipa's easily.

First I also tried testing my app without such a service - but I ended up using this, since it's also very easy for the testers.

Comment: Isn't it scary to upload an application to them before I am live on the app store?

Comment: no why do you think so? The logic is basically the same as you are used to - you need to add each tester's device, then you need to create the ad hoc certificate with the tester's device and then upload your app. Then you send an info that the app is uploaded to each tester - only those testers have access to your app which you authorized in the first place - buttom line - it is as save as Apple's approach, just much more comfortable to use.

Comment: I didn't get what is the advantage over Apple

Comment: just look at their homepage - it's just more comfortable to manage all your test users, invitations to new testers, apps, groups of testers, information for testers,... Also they respond directly to your question in very short time - I was impressed what kind of free service is available these days....

Comment: Note it's only free for a time; they will start charging when they get popular enough.

Comment: I created an easy way to share your IPA file.  http://www.ipashare.com It's a cross between testflight and pastebin

Comment: Thank you  but this will only work if you have added the tester's iPhone ID to your certificate!

Answer (score 1):

Create Distribution certificate and Provisioning profile.
You should have the Distribution certificate in key-chain.
Download Distribution Provisioning profile and double click on that profile.
Confirm you are having the profile in XCode -> Organizer.

Answer (score 1):

In case the Add-Hoc deployment won't install on a testing device, and you have the device added to the profile, and the app signed correctly ...

Ok, what I did is to add an `Entitlements.plist` file and set the `Can be debugged` option to `NO` and set it on the target as the `Code Signing Entitlements`, but actually I don't know if this was the fix because I won't try again and again, now that it worked.

Then, actually I didn't archive the app and save the .ipa file from `Organizer - Archives`, but instead I've sent the .app file from the `build/Release-iphoneos` as it is, together with the profile downloaded from dev account. It will install in iTunes and it just worked, after couple of hours of frustration.